# Google extension: trigger ajaxtooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

Maybe who know something about [ajaxtooltip](http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/ajaxtooltip.shtml). I need trigger in main page content this tooltip in *iframe* element. I tryed this code

```js
someIframe.find("*").trigger('hover');
```

But it gave nothing. Tooltip work well when I hover cursor on link. But I want call all tooltips. How do I can realize it?

Comment: I don't know about *ajaxtooltip*, but keep in mind that content scripts have a different scope than the target page.

Comment: **Derek 朕會功夫**, I have considered it. My target is trigger event handler this tooltip. Tooltip event handler declaration in target page. Maybe jQuery   no access for trigger event handler?